# How do I inspect Zeitgeist

Tags: 13.04, zeitgeist

On Ubuntu 13.04, is there a tool that allows me to inspect the contents of the Zeitgeist logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the `gnome-activity-journal` app in 13.04. It's in the archives. All you have to do is install and run it.